# Tag Request - Highschool Level Physics

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

I suggest, that we introduce a High-School-Level Tag, as opposed to Graduate Level Physics(Currently Called Research-Level), To Bring a Basic Level Filtering system into action.

There is some ambiguity about what qualifies as High school(depending on where you studied), For most purposes, there will be little confusion on when It can be applied.

Here is a list of sample questions that this tag can be applied to, [calculating-a-torque](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70626/calculating-a-torque)
, [centrifugal-force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/73672/centrifugal-force) and [understanding-the-basics-of-electromagnetic-induction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/73622/understanding-the-basics-of-electromagnetic-induction) and [density-of-air-in-a-balloon](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/73473/density-of-air-in-a-balloon)

Comment: Yep, this could be helpful too if properly used.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons not to do this, some social, some technical, but...

> There is some ambiguity about what qualifies as High school(depending on where you studied)

That alone is reason enough not to put any more thought into it. You should be able to read a question and *know* which tags apply.